# React Native Alert auto hide and dissapear

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, alert

I have an issue with [Alert](https://reactnative.dev/docs/alert) in react native.

I'm using alert to show messages to the user. In android, Alert works fine but in iOS Alert will pop up and disappear automatically.

Code :

```
export const loginUser = (values) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    console.log("REDUX THUNK STARTED !");
    console.log("GET DATA FROM : ", Helpers.USER_LOGIN);
    dispatch(onLoginRequest(true));

    fetch(Helpers.USER_LOGIN, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: values.userEmail,
        password: values.userPassword,
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch(onLoginRequest(false));

        console.log("Response Status from the URL - ", res.status);
        console.log("REDUX THUNK COMPLETE !");

        //Handle the response accordingly
        if (res.status == "200") {
          values.navigation.navigate("HomeScreen");
          dispatch(onLoginSuccess(true));
        } else if (res.status == "400") {
          //Invalid credentails
          Alert.alert(
            "Error",
            "Please Check Email and Password",
            [{ text: "OK", onPress: () => dispatch(onLoginSuccess(false)) }],
            { cancelable: false }
          );
        } else {
          errorDialog.globalError();
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.warn("URL Fetch Error - ", e);
        dispatch(onLoginRequest(false));
        dispatch(onLoginFailure(true));
        console.log("REDUX THUNK ERROR !");
        errorDialog.globalError();
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: @高鵬翔 Alertios is deprecated and can't use. The above link is not my question. In my scenario Alert automatically close. Android will not automatically close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. The issue is with my Loading spinner overlay [library](https://github.com/joinspontaneous/react-native-loading-spinner-overlay)

It will automatically close the Alert

As a solution, I added setTimeout function for alert

Code

```
setTimeout(() => {
            Alert.alert(
              'Error',
              'Please Check Email and Password',
              [{text: 'OK', onPress: () => dispatch(onLoginSuccess(false))}],
              {cancelable: false},
            );
          }, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add async await or promise

```
else if (res.status == "400") {
showAlert();
}
```

```
function showAlert(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Alert.alert(
     "Error",
     "Please Check Email and Password",
      [
        {text: 'Ok', onPress: () => {resolve('ok') },
      ],
      {cancelable: false},
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: It didn't help. Still has the issue. Automatically error alert is closing

Comment: Can you post your complete function?

Comment: Same issue. I updated my code with your answer but still the issue have

Comment: Thanks for the time and I found the bug :)

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: The issue is with the loading spinner overlay package. It forces Alert to close